# I got an error, after add my cpanel smtp mail service with nodemailer,

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

**I got this error please help me , i am stuck , its happening with my cpanel smtp server.
This is error in my terminal:**

*Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 76.76.21.21:465
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
errno: -4039,
code: 'ESOCKET',
}*

My Code:

```
// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper

async function main() {

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({

    host: "workbes.com",

    port: 465,

    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports

    auth: {

      user: 'customer@workbes.com', // generated ethereal user

      pass: 'mypassword', // generated ethereal password

    },

    tls: {

      rejectUnauthorized:false

    }

  });

  // send mail with defined transport object

  let info = await transporter.sendMail({

    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address

    to: "almafuz97@gmail.com", // list of receivers

    subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line

    text: "Hello world?", // plain text body

    html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body

  });

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

  // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...

}

main().catch(console.error);
```